# Quais os cenários ideais de uso para o Node.js?

Tags: javascript, banco-de-dados, node.js

O tema é amplo, mas vou tentar focar no que realmente preciso entender.

Ultimamente tenho estudado o Node.js, e tenho me surpreendido com a ferramenta, nos comparativos que vi, parece ser uma ferramenta madura e eficaz.

Em muitos lugares, vejo recomendações de uso quando o foco da aplicação é escalabilidade, pois o node é Single Thread.

Porém estou a desenvolver uma aplicação relativamente grande, ao menos de funcionalidades. e estou em dúvidas em qual ferramenta utilizar no Back-End.

Basicamente a aplicação terá:

- WebService RESTful no BackEnd(Java ou Node.js).
- Banco de dados Relacional(Postgres);
- Front-End com AngularJS(Web) e Android(Ionic) pra Mobile(Ainda não decidi).

> As minhas dúvidas sao as seguintes:
>
> - Em que cenários o Node.js é recomendável a sua utilização, e quais cenários devo evitar?
> - Nesse modelo acima, o Node.js se enquadra ou seria melhor utilizar outra ferramenta no Back-End?
> - O Node.js foi feito para trabalhar com requisições sequenciais(fazer uma requisição e aguardar o retorno na mesma "transação")?
> - Como o Node.js se comporta com banco de dados Relacionais(postgres), o sistema acima, provavelmente terá muitas consultas ao Bd, esse cenário é compatível com a ferramenta ?

Comment: `uso quando quiser alta performance e um consumo menor de memória no servidor` depende de comparação com o que, né? :) O pessoal faz umas afirmações por aí que são tão esquisitas, não é a tecnologia que faz a diferença, é a forma como usa.

Comment: Concordo com o @bigown ^ . Eu uso Node.js diáriamente, funciona mto estável. Pessoalmente acho a pergunta ampla demais.

Comment: @Sergio aí já não sei, eu não conheço o suficiente pra julgar se é ampla. Parece um pouco.

Comment: Sim, concordo, acho que ficou esquisito a colocação, mas li em vários locais, se não exatamente, muito parecido a frase. com relação a abordagem, o que eu poderia melhorar para não deixar a pergunta tão ampla?

Comment: A única pergunta que é válida depois da leitura seria a seguinte: Quais são as boas práticas para programar um servidor web? Pergunta essa que não foi colocada.

Comment: @BrunoCosta Acho que foge um pouco do contexto da minha pergunta, resumidamente queria entender se o Node.js se aplica ao modelo de software acima, se é recomendável sua utilização.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Peço desculpa, mas para dar uma resposta completa vou ter que fugir um bocado aquilo que está a ser perguntado.

A sua pergunta últimamente refere-se apenas a um dos problemas que os servidores `web` têm que
responder. Esse problema é o Throughput (pedidos respondidos por unidade de tempo (minutos)).

É de lembrar que o processamento (instruções do código) é sempre efetuado numa thread.
E isto continua a ser verdade quando se está a programar um servidor web, cuja responsabilidade é a seguinte:

- Receber pedidos
- Processar o pedido
- Enviar a resposta

Uma particularidade é que grande parte deste processamento trata-se de processamento de I/O
(receber pedidos e enviar respostas).
E enquanto o pedido de procesamento de I/O não é resolvido o CPU pode continuar a processar os restantes pedidos.

Mas isto só pode acontecer se os **pedidos de I/O forem feitos de forma assíncrona**.

Vamos exemplificar o que acontece num pedido sincrono e assincrono de I/O, com 2 pedidos de leitura ao ficheiro A e B 
e imaginemos que queremos procurar uma certa palavra em ambos os ficheiros.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como pode ver, se o processamento for feito de forma assíncrona, o tempo total será menor.
Na verdade o tempo total vai corresponder ao seguinte:

Tempo = Max(Processamento I/O A, Processamento I/O B) + Pesquisa palavra em A + Pesquisa palavra em B

Agora que sabemos porque o **processamento de I/O assincrono** é benéfico podemos apresentar 
boas práticas que devem ser seguidas **sempre** mas também quando estamos a desenvolver um servidor web.

- Todos os pedidos de I/O são feitos de forma assíncrona.
- De forma geral uma thread nunca fica bloqueada à espera de I/O.

---

Agora se quem está a ler esta resposta sabe aquilo que eu expliquei e conhece o Node, 
sabe que foi feito um investimento bastante grande para proporcionar APIs que processam os pedidos de I/O de forma assincrona.
Ainda assim, na leitura de ficheiros, por exemplo, é possível fazer de forma sincrona.

E é isto que permite ao Node ter um throughput tão grande "apenas" com uma thread. 
Mas no fim também é trabalho do programador assegurar que não existem pedidos de I/O a serem feitos de forma sincrona.

Se esta mesma prática for aplicada com outras técnologias **NUNCA** será possível que apenas 1 thread possa ter um maior throughput de por exemplo 4 threads **num CPU de 4 cores**.
Contúdo poderão haver muitas outras razões para que uma ou outra técnologia seja melhor num determinado cenário, e que ainda assim o Node possa ter um desempenho melhor que outra que seja multi-threaded.

Essas razões podem ser, mas não estão limitadas a:

- Implementação das maquinas virtuais bastante diferente
- Implementação das APIs disponiveis bastante diferente
- Linguagem interpretada vs linguagem duplamente compilada
- ...

Mas isto não é de todo um fator limitador para o Node. Pois o mesmo efeito pode ser alcançádo lançando 4 processos do mesmo servidor e designa-los a cores diferentes.
Desta forma o Node também terá a capacidade de utilizar todas os cores de um processador para tratar dos pedidos.

> Como o Node.js se comporta com banco de dados Relacionais(postgres), o sistema acima, provavelmente terá muitas consultas ao Bd, esse cenário é compatível com a ferramenta?

Adivinhe, uma consulta no banco de dados é um pedido de I/O. Se for feito de forma assíncrona, como mencionei, não interessa se é feito em Node ou não.

> O Node.js foi feito para trabalhar com requisições sequenciais(fazer uma requisição e aguardar o retorno na mesma "transação")?

Duas requisições sequenciais também podem ser feitas de forma assíncrona. A diferença é que a segunda só pode ter inicio quando a primeira estiver completa.

Comment: Acrescento, que no meu exemplo de leituras de ficheiros não existem nenhumas garantias que o pedido de leitura do ficheiro A seja satisfeito primeiro que o da leitura do ficheiro B, mesmo que este tenha sido feito em primeiro lugar.