# O que é o assincronismo?

Tags: assincronismo

Numa pergunta sobre [usar ou não usar o Node Js](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/123986), acabei por ter que dar uma explicação sobre [o que é o assincronismo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/123986/124013#124013).

E parece que a comunidade beneficiaria de uma forma geral duma explicação formal de **O que afinal é o assincronismo?**.

Apesar de ter intenções de re-aproveitar o conteúdo que postei todos são convidados a responder.

**Referências:**

Faço desde já referência à pergunta [Como programação assíncrona funciona em JavaScript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16950). No entanto a intenção é explicar de forma abstracta e sem ligação a qualquer linguagem o que é e como funciona a programação assíncrona.

Referência à [Qual a vantagem real de usar um CallBack e o que é thread/multithread?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/45706/45721#45721). Quer a pergunta quer a resposta tocam neste tópico, mas tudo parte dum meio para atingir um fim. Antes de perceber o que são e como são usados os callbacks na programação assíncrona é necessário perceber o que é ela é.

Comment: Veja se o desenho nesta resposta ajuda http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/45721/3635 :)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Adicionei às referências, obrigado pela contribuição, e parabéns pela sua boa resposta a essa pergunta.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**O que é o assincronismo?**

> Síncrono ou assíncrono diz respeito ao fluxo de execução de um programa.
>   Quando uma operação executa completamente antes de passar o controle à seguinte, a execução é síncrona. @bfavaretto

Segue uma imagem explicativa do fluxo de execução síncrona e assíncrona, 
retirada da minha resposta a [Quando utilizar Node.js e quando não utilizar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/123986)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Pode-se fazer a analogia de uma operação assíncrona ao agendamento de uma operação. A thread agenda a operação e pode continuar a execução normalmente.
Quando a operação assíncrona estiver concluída a thread tem oportunidade de processar o seu resultado.
Essa oportunidade normalmente é criada usando **callbacks** (Ponteiros para funções).

Vamos dar um exemplo: Faz um pedido assíncrono à API do SE, quando este pedido estiver completo executa a função A

```js
var now = performance.now();
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

function A() {
  if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
    document.getElementById("result").textContent = "API SE " + ~~(performance.now() - now) + "ms";
  }
}
request.onreadystatechange = A; //quando este pedido estiver completo executa a função A
request.open('GET', 'https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers?order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow', true);
request.send(); //faz um pedido assincrono à API do SE
```

```html
<p id="result"></p>
```

**Quando e porquê é útil programar assíncronamente?**

- Quando uma operação é demorada

Se uma operação é demorada a thread que a está a executar teria que esperar até que ela completasse.

- Para não bloquear a user-interface (mesma razão acima, vista de uma forma diferente)

Normalmente as user-interfaces processam eventos (cliques em botões, movimento do rato, teclas, ...).
Estes mesmos eventos não devem demorar muito tempo para que a user-interface possa continuar a processá-los.

- Quando uma operação é uma operação de I/O

**O que é que não é o assincronismo?**

- Operações assíncronas não garantem nenhum paralelismo com excepção se forem operações de I/O.
- Operações assíncronas não implicam o envolvimento de outras threads para execução de código

**Porquê é que é o I/O assíncrono é "especial"?**

Este é o único tipo de assincronismo que permite paralelismo, este paralelismo ocorre sempre a nível de hardware distinto
do CPU (discos, placas de rede, ...).

Conforme mostrei na Imagem 1 se os pedidos de I/O fossem de forma assincrona o tempo total seria menor.
O tempo total pode ser calculado:

```
Tempo total = Max(Processamento I/O A, Processamento I/O B) + Processa A + Processa B
```

Comment: Eu não aceitei a resposta do @bfavarento porque ele não falou do I/O assincrono e devido à organização da sua resposta.

Answer (score 25):

## Definições

*Síncrono* ou *assíncrono* diz respeito ao fluxo de execução de um programa. Quando uma operação executa **completamente** antes de passar o controle à seguinte, a execução é *síncrona*. Esse é o método padrão de execução de código – nas linguagens que eu conheço, e imagino que também na maioria das que não conheço.

Quando uma ou mais operações são demoradas, pode ser interessante executá-las de maneira *assíncrona*, para que o restante do código possa ser executado sem precisar esperar que elas terminem. Nesse caso, o código seguinte ao comando que dispara a operação assíncrona não pode contar com o resultado dessa operação, naturalmente. Tudo que dependa do resultado da operação precisa ser feito somente quando ela tiver sido concluída, e geralmente isso ocorre num *callback*, isto é, um bloco de código (geralmente uma função ou método) informado ao comando que inicia a operação assíncrona.

As linguagens podem implementar o assincronismo de diferentes maneiras. Geralmente isso é feito com Threads e loops de eventos, [como em JavaScript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/16960).

## Exemplos

Em JavaScript, no browser, o caso clássico de operação assíncrona é o AJAX – sigla em inglês para JavaScript e XML *assíncronos*. Chamamos de AJAX as requisições feitas a um servidor a partir do JS em uma página web. Por exemplo, com jQuery para abreviar:

```js
$.get('http://example.com', funcaoQueExecutaQuandoRespostaChegar);

// o código seguinte executa antes da resposta da requisição acima
fazAlgumaCoisa();

// e a declaração do callback
function funcaoQueExecutaQuandoRespostaChegar(resposta) {
    // a resposta não pode ser usada fora daqui,
    // a menos que você a passe, a partir daqui,
    // para uma outra função
}
```

Como a requisição é potencialmente demorada (e certamente mais demorada que qualquer operação local), se ela for feita de maneira síncrona a página ficará congelada enquanto a resposta não chegar. Por isso recomenda-se usar AJAX e *callbacks* nesses casos.

Outro exemplo típico ocorre na interface de usuário de aplicações Desktop. Se o programa quiser mostrar uma barra de progresso indicando o andamento de uma operação demorada, precisa necessariamente utilizar assincronismo. Caso contrário a interface só poderá atualizar a barra de progresso uma vez, ao final da operação – o que não faria nenhum sentido para uma barra de progresso!

Comment: Este é um excelente começo, obrigado por começar pela definição do que é o assincronismo e ainda tocar na diferença entre a execução síncrona e assíncrona. Mas eu estou à procura duma resposta que possa explicar a praticamente a uma criança e que esteja bastante completa.

Comment: Ok. Eu infelizmente ando sem tempo para escrever respostas muito detalhadas. Quem sabe no futuro :) Eu quis responder porque aquela minha resposta sobre js é técnica demais e para um público muito específico, e vi uma oportunidade para deixar as definições aqui, de forma sucinta. Também espero que apareçam respostas melhores e mais completas.

Comment: Complementei um pouco. Deixo para outros falarem de promises e como "domar" código assíncrono.