# Porque o AJAX permite a utilização de forma síncrona?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Olá, nos meus estudos sobre AJAX, a forma de transmissão síncrona é sempre vista com maus olhos, sendo que a forma amplamente recomendada de transmissão seja assíncrona. Se somente assíncrona é a que devemos usar, alguém consegue explicar em qual situação fatalmente vou ter que usar o AJAX de forma síncrona? Melhorando a pergunta: quando a forma síncrona terá importância real de uso? Obrigada.

Comment: Se após o usuário executar uma ação, você não quer que ele saia da sua página de jeito nenhum, até a ação ser concluída, é uma boa hora para usar AJAX de forma síncrona.

Comment: Minha visão é que esta funcionalidade visava deixar o código mais "fácil" de escrever, já que muitos programadores têm dificuldade em lidar com *callbacks* e execução assíncrona, além do que isso evita o "trabalho adicional" de bloquear requisições repetidas caso o usuário clique várias vezes num botão, por exemplo, e também evita a necessidade de colocar algum tipo de *loader* para o usuário. Enfim, solução "porca" para programador preguiçoso (ou desavisado) que demora anos para ser removida porque tem muita gente com essas características por aí. Pelo menos esta é minha opinião. :)

Comment: Veja tambem [O que é o assincronismo?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/124283)

Comment: Estes links podem ser úteis: [*Ajax não é uma linguagem de programação. Então o que é?*](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/116153/3635) e [Qual a vantagem real de usar um CallBack e o que é thread/multithread?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/45706/3635)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O problema com pedidos síncronos é que a aplicação fica paralizada e dependente de algo externo para funcionar.

No caso de o servidor, ou a ligação de internet tiverem problemas e a resposta não chegar a aplicação está bloqueada, nada acontece. Nem mesmo um possivel `setTimeout` para fazer reset ao ajax... nada. Isto é muito mau e por isso está a ser removida esta possibilidade do mundo JavaScript.

Ainda [houve quem referisse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4316512/2256325) em 2010 que é bom utilizar esta técnica como ultimo recurso para o `onbeforeunload`, ou seja quando o utilizador fecha o browser e a aplicação precisa de comunicar com o servidor. Mas mesmo aqui é má ideia. Aliás via jQuery já não é possível nas novas versões, isso está deprecado. As [especificações de xhr](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#sync-warning) e da [w3c](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-XMLHttpRequest-20120117/#the-open-method) vão nessa direção também.