# "Filter" não está defenida

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Olá, eu tenho um script simples que a partir de algumas pesquisas no stackoverflow eu construí.

Depois quando comecei a colocar mais algum conteúdo os scripts começaram a deixar de funcionar e a apresentar alguns erros, eu ja consegui resolver alguns mas existem dois erros que não estou a conseguir resolver que me aparecem na consola:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Coloquei a versão mais actualizada do Ajax e jQuery mas algo não esta a funcionar, será que alguém me pode ajudar a resolver este erro?

O objectivo do script exibido é ao entrar na pagina executar automaticamente a função `showPeople();`

```js
function LoadJsonData(callback) {
    $.ajax({
      url: './Json/dados.json',
      dataType: 'json',
      async: false,
      success: function (json) {
        if (callback) callback(json);
      }
    });
  }

var jsondata = LoadJsonData();

showPeople();

function showPeople() {


    var filtroFaixaEtaria = $("#FaixaEtaria option:selected").text();
    var filtroSexo = $("#Sexo option:selected").text();
    var filtroRecursoArma = $("#RecursoArma option:selected").text();
    var filtroDistrito = $("#Distrito option:selected").text();

    var arrayResultados = jsondata.filter(function (item) {
        var criteria = true;

        if (filtroFaixaEtaria != null && filtroFaixaEtaria != "")
            criteria = criteria && item["Faixa Etaria"] == filtroFaixaEtaria;
        if (filtroSexo != null && filtroSexo != "")
            criteria = criteria && item["Sexo"] == filtroSexo;
        if (filtroRecursoArma != null && filtroRecursoArma != "")
            criteria = criteria && item["RecursoArma"] == filtroRecursoArma;
        if (filtroDistrito != null && filtroDistrito != "")
            criteria = criteria && item["Distrito"] == filtroDistrito;


        return criteria;

    });

    document.getElementById("contadorprincipal").innerHTML = arrayResultados.length;

    document.getElementById("contadordebonecos").innerHTML = arrayResultados.length + " / " + arrayResultados.length;

    console.log("Foram encontrados " + arrayResultados.length + " elementos de acordo com a busca");
    const imagens = Array.from({
        length: Number(arrayResultados.length)
    }).reduce((html) => html + imagem, '');
    $('#images').html(imagens);

    console.log("Foram encontrados " + arrayResultados.length + " elementos de acordo com a busca");
    const imagenss = Array.from({
        length: Number(arrayResultados.length)
    }).reduce((html) => html + imagemm, '');
    $('#imagess').html(imagenss);
}
```

Comment: O seu problema deve ser porque você está utilizando um método filter() em um resultado nulo... tente regularizar para que seja um array vazio quando não tiver valor: `[].filter( ... )`, [aqui tem mais informações sobre isso](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filtro).

Comment: Seu problema é de assincronismo. Ao chamar a função showPeople, o valor de jsondata ainda é indefinido.

Comment: @IvanFerrer eu tive a ver mas o meu objectivo e filtrar os casos do json, pois esse filtro é uma função que uso num select e o show people e para o site exibir o numero total de casos no json

Comment: @Sam Como é que eu posso defenir o valor do jsondata? o objetivo do script é analizar qual dos selects estao selecionados para depois definir quantos é que vai definir ao executar a paginar não existe nenhum select selecionado

Comment: Para verificar se está definido: `if(typeof jsondata !== 'undefined') { ... }`

Answer (score 1):

Faça da seguinte forma, chamando a função `LoadJsonData` enviando como parâmetro do callback a função `showPeople`. O valor da variável `jsondata` será enviado pelo callback do Ajax para a função `showPeople` via parâmetro.

E retire a opção `async: false,` do Ajax. Usar Ajax de forma síncrona é desencorajado ([veja esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/124396/8063)).

Seu código deve ficar assim:

```
function LoadJsonData(callback) {
    $.ajax({
      url: './Json/dados.json',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function (json) {
        if (callback) callback(json);
      }
    });
  }

LoadJsonData(showPeople);

function showPeople(jsondata) {
   // resto do código
}
```

Comment: Continuou com o mesmo erro do showPeople e apareceram mais erros eu vou tentar rescrever de outra forma este código está muito estranho... mas obrigado na mesma!

Answer (score 0):

Tenta assim e veja se funciona:

```
function LoadJsonData(callback) {
    $.ajax({
      url: './Json/dados.json',
      dataType: 'json',
      async: false,
      success: function (json) {
        if (callback) callback(json);
      }
    });
  }

var jsondata = LoadJsonData(function(json){
    showPeople(json);
});

jsondata();


function showPeople(jsondataResult) {


    var filtroFaixaEtaria = $("#FaixaEtaria option:selected").text();
    var filtroSexo = $("#Sexo option:selected").text();
    var filtroRecursoArma = $("#RecursoArma option:selected").text();
    var filtroDistrito = $("#Distrito option:selected").text();

    var arrayResultados = jsondataResult.filter(function (item) {
        var criteria = true;

        if (filtroFaixaEtaria != null && filtroFaixaEtaria != "")
            criteria = criteria && item["Faixa Etaria"] == filtroFaixaEtaria;
        if (filtroSexo != null && filtroSexo != "")
            criteria = criteria && item["Sexo"] == filtroSexo;
        if (filtroRecursoArma != null && filtroRecursoArma != "")
            criteria = criteria && item["RecursoArma"] == filtroRecursoArma;
        if (filtroDistrito != null && filtroDistrito != "")
            criteria = criteria && item["Distrito"] == filtroDistrito;


        return criteria;

    });

    document.getElementById("contadorprincipal").innerHTML = arrayResultados.length;

    document.getElementById("contadordebonecos").innerHTML = arrayResultados.length + " / " + arrayResultados.length;

    console.log("Foram encontrados " + arrayResultados.length + " elementos de acordo com a busca");
    const imagens = Array.from({
        length: Number(arrayResultados.length)
    }).reduce((html) => html + imagem, '');
    $('#images').html(imagens);

    console.log("Foram encontrados " + arrayResultados.length + " elementos de acordo com a busca");
    const imagenss = Array.from({
        length: Number(arrayResultados.length)
    }).reduce((html) => html + imagemm, '');
    $('#imagess').html(imagenss);
}
```