# O meu array fica sempre sem conteúdo

Tags: javascript

Estou com um desafio ao fazer chamadas ajax em JQuery.

declarei um array e depois de uma chamada ajax que faço para enviar uma requisição tipo POST, quero pegar o id do novo objecto e armazenar no meu array. A seguir o código.

```
 // Change view_1 to the view you want to listen to
$(document).on('knack-record-create.view_16', function(event, view, record) {


    var iterator = 0;
    var stagesIdToPopulate = [];

    stages = data.records; //console.log(stages);

    stages.forEach(function (stage) {

     var data1 = {field_88:stage.field_30, field_89:stage.id, field_90:stage.id, field_100:"5ba465ed83e85c2ffbda540f"};
  var processItemStagesURL = "https://api.knack.com/v1/objects/object_16/records";
        console.log(iterator);

       $.ajax({
                url:processItemStagesURL,
                type: 'POST',
                headers: headers,
                data: JSON.stringify(data1),
                }).done( function (response) {
                    //stagesIdToPopulate[iterator] = response.id;
                    stagesIdToPopulate.push(response.id);
                    //stagesIdToPopulate = a(stagesIdToPopulate,iterator,response);
                    console.log('Record Added! Its Id is: ' + stagesIdToPopulate);
                });

iterator++;

            }) // fim do foreach

 console.log('Este array nunca tem valor: ________' + stagesIdToPopulate);
});
```

Alguem pode ajudar-me a entender o porquê o my array depoi do for nunca tem conteúdo sff? Obrigado desde já.

Comment: Não é "nunca", é que você está tentando imprimir o valor antes de o servidor retornar uma resposta. Esse código é assíncrono. Ver [O que é o assincronismo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/124283/).

Comment: Quando imprimo nesta linha  console.log('Record Added! Its Id is: ' + stagesIdToPopulate); o já tem conteúdo mas na última linha não isso é que não percebo.

Comment: `$.ajax({` é assincrono. Hipoteticamente pode levar 30 segundos ou um minuto até executar `}).done( function (response) { stagesIdToPopulate.push(response.id);` e entretanto o `console.log('Este array nunca tem valor: ________' + stagesIdToPopulate);` já foi executado.  Comece por ler sobre assincronismo e perceber como funciona.

Comment: Obrigado a todos já dei uma olhada nos links que enviaram e consegui solucionar o meu desafio.