# Não retorna o valor do Número de mensagens por ler

Tags: javascript

Pretendo mostrar o número de mensagens por ler. Estou a usar o seguinte código:
Onde retorna o valor das mensagens por ler:

```
<a href="#" class="notification"> <input type="button" id="btn-mensagem" name="btn-mensagem" class="botao" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-mensagem" style="float: right; margin-right:15%;"> <span class="badge" id='msgNumero'></span>  </a>
```

Estou a usar o seguinte script:

```
function novasMensagens(numero){
  $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url : './fetchbusca',
      success : function(data) {
          var numero = data;    
          var retorno = numero > 0 ? "" : numero;   

document.getElementById("msgNumero").innerHTML = novasMensagens(numero);          
      }   
  });

}
```

Não retorna o valor, como mostro na imagem:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Já tentou colocar dessa forma `document.getElementById("msgNumero").innerHTML = retorno; ` ?

Comment: @JrD já mas não mostra o alerta, fica como na segunda imagem

Comment: O que `console.log(data)` retorna?

Comment: Queira [edit] seu post e reduzir o problema a um [mcve] para viabilizar uma resposta dentro do modelo do site. Mais detalhes em [Tour] e [Help].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considerando que a requisição AJAX é [assíncrona](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/124283/o-que-%C3%A9-o-assincronismo), você deve popular seu balãozinho no método `success` da requisição. Veja:

```
function novasMensagens(){ // não precisa do parâmetro: numero
  $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url : './fetchbusca',
      success : function(data) {
          //var numero = data;    
          //var retorno = numero > 0 ? "" : numero;
          document.getElementById("msgNumero").innerHTML = data;
      }   
  });

}
```

Logo, é só chamar a função e ao concluir ela vai popular o elemento `#msgNumero` com o retorno da requisição.

Isso quer dizer que você não vai chamar a função assim:

```
document.getElementById("msgNumero").innerHTML = novasMensagens(5); // chamada errada!
```

Agora, basta chamar a função diretamente no seu script:

```
novasMensagens();
```

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91825/discussion-on-answer-by-lipespry-nao-retorna-o-valor-o-numero-de-mensagens-por-l) - caso queiram prosseguir, basta clicar no link

Comment: @Bacco Obrigado, mas eu já havia aberto um [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91822/nao-retorna-o-valor-o-numero-de-mensagens-por-ler) com o AP. Pode apagar esse outro aí! Vlw!