# Como armazenar dados enviadas de uma API em uma variável no IONIC 4?

Tags: angular, ionic

Eu tenho uma função no ionic que recebe da API um array e mostra os dados recebido

```
public info;

  async showinfo() {
    await this.authService.getInfo().subscribe(
      data=>{
        this.info = data;
        console.log(data);
        for(let i=0; i<data.length; i++){
          this.info[i];
        }
    },
    error=>{
      console.log(error);
    });

    console.log(this.info); //aparece undefined
 }
```

Quando eu dou um console.log() dentro do subscribe eu consigo ver o valor que eu recebo da API porém se eu tento ver o valor fora dele, ele não mostra o dado.
Como eu faço para ver fora do subscribe o valor da variável??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso ocorre porque você está realizando uma operação [assíncrona](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/124297/77268). O código fora do `subscribe` é executado antes, por isso o `undefined` na saída do console.

Uma solução seria criar um método para manipular a variável `info` e chamá-lo dentro da inscrição do Observable. Desta forma, a manipulação ocorre após atribuição de algum valor para `info`

**Exemplo:**

```
public info;

async showinfo() {
 await this.authService.getInfo().subscribe(
  data => {
   this.info = data;
   console.log(data);
   for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    this.info[i];
   }
   handleInfo();
  },
  error => {
   console.log(error);
  });
}


handleInfo() { // realiza a manipulação de info
 console.log(this.info);
}
```

Comment: muito obrigado!!!!