# Retornar dados de uma requisição HTTP no Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Preciso fazer uma requisição simples que retornará apenas um JSON. 
Estou tentando fazer isso utilizando a seguinte função:

`.ts`:

```
getModel(modelId: number) {
  let modelName: any = "none";
  this.carService.getModel(modelId).subscribe(
    data => modelName = data['name']);
  return modelName;
}
```

`service`:

```
getModel(id: number) {
    return this.http.get<any[]>(`${this.getModelByIdUrl + id}`);
}
```

Mas ele retorna `undefined`. Consegue encontrar certinho, mas não atribui a variavel `modelName`.
Como posso fazer isso? Só preciso que a função retorne o que recebeu da requisição.

Comment: Acho que faltou vc passar todo o contexto do que precisa, pq eu não entendi pq vc utiliza o **service** dentro de uma função. Aonde vc chama a função **`getModel(modelId: number)`**?? Pq ao que parece está redundante esta função.

Answer (score 2):

O que acontece é que `http.get` é uma chamada [assíncrona](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/124283/o-que-%C3%A9-o-assincronismo), ou seja, não é garantido que ela vai retornar os resultados imediatamente, e o `return` pode inclusive executar antes do `get` terminar. `http.get` retorna um [`Observable`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/observable), cujo método `subscribe` serve para indicar o que fazer quando algo for retornado. Então no seu código:

```
this.carService.getModel(modelId).subscribe(
  data => modelName = data['name']);

return modelName;
```

A função que está dentro do `subscribe` (o código `data => modelName = data['name']`, que usa a sintaxe de [*arrow function*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)) é um [*callback*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/27177/112052): ela não executa imediatamente. Você só está dizendo: **quando** o `http.get` retornar algo, execute isso.

Só que a chamada HTTP pode demorar, e o `return` pode ser executado antes do *callback*. Ou seja, você pode acabar retornando o `modelName` antes dele ser setado.

---

Mas não ficou claro para que você precisa retornar esta informação. Por que não usá-la diretamente dentro do próprio *callback*? Ex:

```
this.carService.getModel(modelId).subscribe(
  data => {
    // use o data['name'] diretamente aqui dentro
  }
);
```

---

Ou, se precisar somente do `name`, você pode usar as operações `pipe` e `map`, para transformar o retorno em outro `Observable`:

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

getModel(modelId: number): Observable<string> {
  return this.carService.getModel(modelId).pipe(
    map(data => data['name'])
  );
}
```

Assim, `getModel` agora retorna um `Observable<string>`, ou seja, contendo somente o valor de `data['name']` (estou assumindo que `data['name']` é uma string; caso não seja, mude o tipo de retorno do `Observable`). O retorno deve continuar sendo um `Observable`, pois a chamada que origina tudo (`http.get`) é assíncrona, então se tentarmos retornar diretamente `data['name']`, caímos no mesmo problema do código original.

Aí você usa `getModel` onde precisar, lembrando que agora o retorno é o `name` (e não mais o objeto `data`):

```
this.getModel(1).subscribe(name => {
  // usar o name do jeito que quiser
});
```

Comment: Bom, fiz o que você sugeriu.  Mas depois, preciso pegar o valor e utilizar. ai li que é preciso utilizar o subscribe, e cai no mesmo problema de antes. 
Só para te contextualizar, estou acessando uma api que retorna um json. só que por exemplo, o modelo é um id. e preciso buscar o nome do modelo utilizando o id. depois jogar todos os dados em uma tabela, bonitinho. Mas sempre bato no mesmo problema...

Comment: @bruna Como o retorno de `http.get` é assíncrono, não tem como usá-lo de forma síncrona (não tem como só retornar o valor como você quer fazer). Se precisa usar os dados retornados pelo `get`, o único jeito garantido é fazer tudo que precisa dentro do `subscribe`, não tem como fugir disso. Você pode inclusive chamar um `subscribe` dentro de outro, ou seja, chamar a API, pegar o resultado em um `subscribe`, e dentro desse `subscribe` pode fazer outra chamada HTTP para buscar o ID e chamar o respectivo `subscribe` (dentro do qual vc joga os dados na tabela), etc.

Answer (score -1):

Bom, tome por exemplo que você está fazendo uma requisição esperando um objeto do Tipo `Car`:

```
  getModel(id: number): Observable<Car> {
    return this.http.get<Car>(`${this.getModelByIdUrl + id}`);
  }
```

é necessário que você especifique na chamada `http.get` que você espera um objeto que seja atribuido ao model `Car`. 
 Assim como é necessário sinalizar que a função retorna um `Observable` do tipo `<Car>`.

Comment: Então, fazer isso não mudou muita coisa pra mim. até porque a função do service já estava funcionando... eu acho que o problema esta na função do .ts, onde faço a atribuição. Já verifiquei e os dados chegam até lá. O problema é que não persiste na variavel modelName... (mas obrigada)