# Array fica vazio fora do escopo da função mesmo estando declarado no escopo global

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

Estou iniciando no Javascript e no NodeJs e não estou conseguindo entender pq mesmo eu declarando um array no escopo global, quando tento acessá-lo fora das funções em que fiz o map o array vem vazio.

Eu li dois arquivos sem nenhum problema e consigo visualizar o conteúdo pelo console, mas só dentro da função, fora dela o array fica vazio, estou precisando usar os conteúdos deles para criar outro arquivo. O conteúdo dos arrays `sigla` e `nome` eu só consigo acessar dentro `readFile`:

```
var fs = require("fs");

let sigla = [];
let nome = [];

fs.readFile("Estados.json", "utf8", (err, data) => {
  let states = JSON.parse(data);
  sigla = states.map((state) => {
    const { ID, Sigla, Nome } = state;
    return {
      id: ID,
      sigla: Sigla,
      estadoNome: Nome,
    };
  });
  console.log(sigla);
});

fs.readFile("Cidades.json", "utf8", (err, data) => {
  let cities = JSON.parse(data);
  nome = cities.map((city) => {
    const { ID, Nome, Estado } = city;
    return {
      id: ID,
      cidadeNome: Nome,
      cidadeEstado: Estado,
    };
  });
  console.log(nome);
});

for (i = 0; i < sigla.length; i++) {
  //prettier-ignore
  fs.writeFile(sigla[i].sigla + ".json",JSON.stringify(cidadeNome),(err) => {}
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A função [`fs.readFile()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback) lê o conteúdo de um arquivo de maneira **assíncrona**. Portanto, provavelmente você está tentando ler o conteúdo dos arrays antes de terminar de ler o arquivo.

Caso precise que a leitura do arquivo seja feita de maneira **síncrona**, você pode utilizar a função [`fs.readFileSync()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options). Os parâmetros são os mesmos, com exceçao do Callback, já que o seu código passará a ser síncrono.

Para mais detalhes sobre assincronismo, veja [O que é o assincronismo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/124283/100416) e [Como programação assíncrona funciona em JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16950/100416).