# Sleep() no javascript

Tags: javascript

Como eu faria algo assim?

```
function blink(){                                        
    let blueBall = document.querySelector('div#blueBall')
    blueBall.style.background = '#028E8E'
    sleep(300)
    blueBall.style.background = '##1dfcfc'
    sleep(300)
    blueBall.style.background = '#cdfefe'
    sleep(300)
    blueBall.style.background = '#028e8e'
}
```

Seria pra umas bolinhas "piscarem", mudando de cor e tal...

Comment: Use setTimeout, não é sincrono como seria um sleep, são callbacks - leia em: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/45721/3635

Comment: Na verdade, use CSS :)

Comment: Eu preciso usar JS nesse projeto :c

Comment: Uma dica, quando for compartilhar alguma dúvida/problema aqui no StackOverflow, tente fazer o problema ser reprodutível. Coloque a div que seria essa "bola" e também algum modo de executar a função (um botão, por exemplo). E mais uma coisa, sua segunda cor está com 2 hashtags `##1dfcfc`

Comment: Muito obrigado pela dica, to iniciando nesse mundo da programação, mas na próxima pergunta irei fazer isso sim

Answer (score 1):

Como o Guilherme falou nos comentários da questão, para resolver o seu problema basta utilizar a função [`setTimeout`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp), que executa uma função de forma [assíncrona](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/124283/157404) após esperar um tempo em milissegundos. Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```js
function changeColor() {
    console.log("Alterando a cor para vermelho...");
}

console.log("Cor atual: Azul");
setTimeout(changeColor, 2000);
```

Agora aproveitando a oportunidade já que eu não vi mais nenhuma outra pergunta no site falando sobre isso, há uma forma de realizar uma espera de forma síncrona em JavaScript.

Se você precisar realmente realizar uma espera sem que o código abaixo seja executado, você pode criar uma Promise que executa o `resolve` dentro de um `setTimeout` dessa forma:

```js
function sleep(milliseconds) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, milliseconds))
}

async function main() {
    console.log('Agora o programa vai "domir" por 2 segundos.');
    await sleep(2000);
    console.log("O programa acaba de acordar :D");
}

main();
```

Como pode ver no código acima, a desvantagem dessa função `sleep` é que ela só pode ser utiliza dentro de uma função assíncrona já que para realizar a espera, você precisa chamar a função utilizando o `await`.

Comment: MUITO obrigado man, resolveu meu problema <3