# Quais os cenários em que o C# tem vantagem em relação a outras linguagens?

Tags: c#, .net, característica-linguagem

Aqui no site tem algumas perguntas semelhantes, por exemplo, [Quais os cenários ideais de uso para o Node.js?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/123986/) e [Por que escolher C ao invés de C++ ou então C++ no lugar de C?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/19073/)

Gostaria de algo nesse sentido porém em ralação ao C# para desenvolver uma aplicação web, quais suas características principais (desempenho, flexibilidade, organização, ...)? Quando seu uso é vantajoso em relação as outras linguagens?

Comment: Quando se pensa em microsoft, acredito que este é o melhor "cenário".

Comment: @WictorChaves então o C# só tem mais vantagem quando deve ser desenvolvido uma aplicação para o Windows? Quando se pode escolher em qual sistema operacional o serviço irá rodar, outras linguagens serão melhores?

Comment: Esta pergunta é muito ampla, porque o c# é utilizado para diversas coisas, desde aplicações web a desktop, a microsoft tem um projeto para rodar suas aplicações no linux por exemplo, mas nada melhor do que rodar em seu sistema operacional nativo certo? Eu particularmente se tivesse um servidor linux preferiria utilizar php já que esta no mercado a mais tempo, e o mesmo seria se tivesse um servidor windows preferiria utilizar o c#, mas como é algo muito amplo cada caso é um caso, mas resumidamente acredito que se pensar em microsoft o melhor é c#.

Comment: @WictorChaves obrigado, editei a pergunta focando no desenvolvimento web

Answer (score 11, accepted):

O Wictor já comentou algo importante, mas isso também é um erro comum.

Raras as linguagens que funcionam tão bem em pilha de tecnologia Microsoft quanto C#. Não por ela, mas pela infraestrutura em volta dela. E convenhamos que em desktop praticamente só olhamos pra Windows.

O erro é achar que C# não é adequada para todas plataformas e está comprometida com tudo o que surgir que seja relevante. Dei uma [palestra sobre isso](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-lVjZVoQViE&feature=youtu.be&t=19m44s).

Onde será usada não é critério.

Vamos entender que C# é uma linguagem do tipo *enterprise*, então ela vem com uma infra muito forte. Ela é de propósito geral, então dá para fazer quase tudo com ela, é melhor perguntar onde ela não se encaixa.

Vou deixar de lado o gosto e a experiência. Isso é importante. Fazer o que gosta ajuda muito. Saber usar bem torna tudo mais produtivo e costuma dar melhor qualidade.

## Performance

O desempenho do C# é excelente e pode bater C ou C++ em códigos mais simples. Claro que o máximo da performance com muito esforço será obtido com C ou C++, ou Assembly em alguns casos. Mas realmente dá muito trabalho. Da minha outra palestra:

[image: Batalha de performance C# vs C++]

C# hoje dá muito mais importância para performance que há 10, 15 anos atrás.

Se por performance está falando de executar *real time*, o que é raro precisar, é possível, mas C# exige muito esforço por causa do *garbage collector*, e em alguns casos *hard real time* não dá.

[.NET Native](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/30793/101) vai ajudar mais na performance no geral. Mas pode piorar em alguns pontos específicos. Note que isso é uma implementação específica do *runtime, nada a ver com a linguagem em si. Ele não terá continuidade, mas parte dos seus benefícios agora está no .NET 5 para frente.

"Cada dia" tem mais novidades para melhorar a performance, mas sempre foi uma linguagem pragmática quanto a isto, em comparação ao idealismo de algumas linguagens, como Java tem.

## Flexibilidade

C# é flexível e versátil, difícil responder algo específico sobre isto, no geral atende quase todas necessidades. É poderosa, consegue resolver razoavelmente bem em quase todas situações, independente de ser só uma forma acadêmica de ver ([*turing complete*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/102452/101)), digo, na prática dá bem.

Dá, mas não é adequada para fazer um sistema operacional ([COSMOS](https://github.com/CosmosOS/Cosmos), [SharpOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SharpOS_(operating_system)), [Singularity](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=singularity), [FlingOS](http://www.flingos.co.uk/), [MOSA](https://github.com/mosa/MOSA-Project) e [Midori](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midori_%28operating_system%29)). Muitas restrições para fazer um bom *driver*. [Não se compara com C++ para isto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/7740/101), o que boa parte da pergunta já está respondida ali.

[Não é uma linguagem de *script*, mas pode ser usada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15428/101) (em C# 9 e 10 para frente isso melhorou muito).

Pode usar [embarcada dentro de alguns bancos de dados](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/introduction-to-sql-server-clr-integration?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

E hoje pode em [navegadores web para fazer *frontend*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/288706/101) (nem falarei em *backend* agora, e tem uma das melhores bibliotecas para isto).

Roda em todas plataformas *mainstream*, incluindo [mobile](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/xamarin/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397), em todos servidores importantes, incluindo em nuvem ([AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/pt/sdk-for-net/), [Google](https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/)), com otimizações próprias para isto ([Azure](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/azure/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397)).

E está cada vez melhor para [IoT](https://www.microsoft.com/net/learn/apps/iot?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

O resto é biblioteca, que tem muito para ela, incluindo Machine Learnig, BigData, jogos, robótica e muito mais.

## Organização

Não sei bem o que isso quer dizer e pode ser algo só baseado em opinião. Considero bem organizada por vários critérios. Tem boa arquitetura, sintaxe, semântica, ecossistema geral, incluindo excelentes [ferramentas de produtividade e qualidade](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/).

## Facilidade

É uma linguagem relativamente fácil para o poder que ela tem, muito mais que C++, e comparando com C, depende. C é mais fácil de aprender e mais difícil de usar, principalmente por ter menos abstrações, menos coisas prontas, e por não ter gerenciamento automático de memória.

É uma linguagem muito bem definida e só não é muito fácil porque envolve muitos conceitos.

Linguagens de *script* são mais fáceis. Mas são menos robustas e menos escaláveis. C# é feita para projetos grandes, que duram, que são altamente relevantes. Tendem a ser mais produtivas no começo.

## *Backend web*

<sub>A pergunta mudou no meio do caminho</sub>

Já falei que roda também em *frontend* (tem palestra minha no TDC 2018), e eu vou com ela firme, ainda que esteja experimental (já está consolidado anos depois). Pro meu gosto acho mais negócio, pelo menos para aplicação, ainda que eu não seja fã de aplicações web, mas tem motivo para usar. Para websites é diferente, eles não podem ser complexos, aí não sei, depende. Acho que [Blazor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/288706/101) será melhor que Angular, React, todas essas coisas.

A linguagem em si muda pouco ou nada para desenvolvimento web no *backend*. Faz mais diferença para a tarefa em si.

C# é mais escalável, como eu disse, mas isso não é uma vantagem tão forte. Linguagens menos escaláveis podem ser usadas em projetos grandes com a cultura certa. E falo de escalar o projeto, não estou falando de escala de execução, isso pode ser feito com qualquer linguagem cop ma infra certa e botando mais dinheiro.

Claro que linguagens mais eficientes podem diminuir a necessidade de escala de execução. C# pode ser dezenas de vezes mais rápida que Ruby, por exemplo, e pode ser que precise de um simples servidor no lugar de vários servidores parrudos. Mas a sua decisão em outros pontos fará mais diferença. O SQLite pode escalar melhor que um SQL Server em alguns cenários, desde que a pessoa saiba o que está fazendo.

Tem sites enormes feitos em cada uma das linguagens *mainstream*, todas beleza. Este aqui é feito em C#, é um dos 30/50 sites mais acessados do mundo, e roda em 11 servidores, mas poderia rodar em apenas 1 com risco de ter gargalos em alguns horários. Tá bom? Não precisa usar linguagens que são potencialmente mais rápidas com esforço para obter bom resultado, e essas linguagens que podem ser mais rápidas correm sério risco de segurança em um ambiente onde isso é absurdamente importante.

Tem sites feitos em linguagens de *script* que escalam bem em performance, com a arquitetura certa, mas custa muito caro. Um dos motivos que eu me recuso contribuir com a Wikipedia porque ela é ecológica e economicamente incorreta. Alguns sites sucumbiram e trocaram de linguagem para uma que escala melhor, o Twitter é um exemplo e Scala é a dica :)

Uma das vantagens do C# é seu ecossistema, não é o melhor, mas tenta ser. Não tem *trocentos* *frameworks*, mas tem um para cada tarefa que aprendeu com os próprios erros e dos outros. E tem como vantagem não ficar preso demais ao legado. Inclusive o [.NET Core](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40671/101) (agora só chamado de .NET) tem sido otimizado para isso. [Tem muita coisa boa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/111209/101). Mas não é a linguagem. Inclusive tudo isso pode ser usado com outras linguagens que rodam em cima do [CLR](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/51281/101).

Tem detalhes, mas nada de muito importante que faça o C# ser menos adequado que outras linguagens. Mas eu defendo outras linguagens quando o projeto é pequeno, não atenderá tanta demanda assim, não durará por muito tempo.

## Extra

Particularmente se mais tempo de mercado for determinante para escolher a linguagem, deveria usar Fortran, ou Lisp, ou COBOL. É comum o que está há mais tempo ser pior porque não pôde aprender com os erros e a linguagem tem um legado ruim muito pesado. Eu usaria PHP para algumas coisas em web, mas de forma geral é uma das linguagens mais erradas já criadas, e a sua evolução costuma ser em cima de novos erros, isso é bem temerário. E não consigo imaginar porque PHP seria melhor no Linux e não no Windows, e porque C# seria bom no Windows e não no Linux.

Tenho críticas ao C#, mas tenho mais às outras linguagens. O que mais gosto de C# e seu ecossistema é que ela está evoluindo muito bem, estão fazendo o que precisa, não na velocidade que eu queria (isso andou melhorando), não tudo o que desejo, e tem motivos para ser assim, mas as outras estão atrás. Tenho gostado também da evolução do C++, mas o legado dela é pesadíssimo. Uma linguagem meio termo entre C++ sem o legado e C# seria sensacional, algo quase unânime e a Microsoft estava desenvolvendo isso, mas acabou (veja Midori acima).

Gosto de algumas iniciativas de linguagens mais recentes, uma linguagem nova ideal olharia para [D](https://dlang.org/), [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org), [Go](https://golang.org/), [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/), [Swift](https://swift.org/), [Nim](https://nim-lang.org/), [Jai](https://www.reddit.com/r/jailang/), [F#](https://fsharp.org/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397), e outras bem menos conhecidas.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Quando fala do C# no frontend, se refere a uma aplicação desktop, certo? O código para desenvolver uma aplicação web é o mesmo para uma aplicação desktop (a parte de acesso a banco e controle de fluxo), certo? Resumindo, o C# só não é uma ótima escolha para projetos simples? Tem alguma linguagem para backend web que possa se equiparar com C# (assim como C e C++ para desktop)?

Comment: Não, falei web. Pra desktop é diferente de web, no geral, a não ser parte que não envolve interação com usuário. O C# é bom para projetos simples, mas pode ter alguma linguagem que seja melhor. Só que tem um detalhe que eu não mencionei, em projetos simples tanto faz :D. Equiparar é um conceito amplo demais :)

Comment: Ainda não conheço a linguagem mas essa resposta deu incentivo final que precisava para eu iniciar no C#, vou começar pelos links que tem no wiki ta tag, obrigado pela ajuda. Mas se equiparar é um conceito muito grande, então, existe alguma linguagem que possa bater um backend bem feito em C# em algum cenário que não seja um projeto simples?

Comment: É difícil dizer pq bater é um conceito mais amplo ainda :D

Comment: " E não consigo imaginar porque PHP seria melhor no Linux e não no Windows, e porque C# seria bom no Windows e não no Linux", Só uma pequena observação, eu levei em consideração as buscas, geralmente quando se pensa em php, se pensa em servidores linux, e quando se pensa em c#, me vem logo na cabeça microsoft, acredito ser importante a gama de conteúdo em relação a linguagem escolhida.

Comment: Mas isso é motivo pra decidir o que é melhor? Inclusive salvo pequenos detalhes, não faz a menor diferença onde a linguagem está rodando, geralmente bem inferior à 1% de tudo o que se faz, portanto não deve ser algo para se considerar. No passado até havia certas dificuldades. Inclusive um dos motivos para não fazer buscas para tomar essas decisões é porque tem muita informação defasada, muita informação errada, muita reprodução equivocada, muita informação incompleta, e *fake news* roda mais fácil que verdadeira. Eu usei + PHP no Windows (qdo era ruim) do q no Linux e hj uso C# mais no Linux